# Why does the compiler recalculate a value that was already available in another register?

Tags: assembly, rust, x86, llvm, compiler-optimization

I’m studying machine code produced by the Rust compiler. Here is a simple function that calculates the sum of all elements in a slice. (In Rust, a slice is essentially an array whose length is generally only known at runtime. It resides in a contiguous region of memory and is described by a pointer to the first element and the number of elements.)

```rust
fn sum_imperative(slice: &[i64]) -> i64 {
    let mut sum = 0;
    for n in slice {
        sum += n;
    }
    sum
}
```

With SSE disabled and optimizations turned on, rustc 1.46.0 [produces code](https://godbolt.org/z/na4rsP) that starts like this:

```asm
example::sum_imperative:
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB0_1
        lea     rax, [8*rsi - 8]
        mov     rdx, rax
        shr     rdx, 3
        add     rdx, 1
```

Here, the number of elements N in the slice is in `rsi`. If my understanding is correct, the code first calculates 8N−8 and stores that in `rax`. Then it uses that result to calculate (8N−8)/8+1 and stores that in `rdx`. Assuming there is no overflow, the `rdx` result should always be equal to the original value of N that is still available in `rsi`.

Why did the compiler recalculate the value of N rather than use one that was already available in `rsi`?

Comment: Yeah, strange, looks like it's computing the byte offset to the last element, and then turning that back into an element count.  Perhaps some Rust logic computes that with unsigned math in such a way that the LLVM back-end thinks it *does* need to preserve the possible truncating behaviour.  That's pure guesswork, but would explain this missed-optimization bug.  (Which you should probably report on the rustc bug tracker.)

Comment: I don't think safe code would be able to overflow `rax`. It's the byte offset of the last element in the slice, after all, and that should definitely fit into a 64-bit register. It's possible that LLVM does not have enough information to proof that the overflow behaviour is not relevant here. In any case, I think you need to bring that up with either the Rust or the LLVM developers to get a useful answer.